# Sequelize - How to set foreign key name in belongs-to-many associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to create the db schema. And I cannot find how to set the foreign key name in a many to many relationship.

I have a **investment_manager** table

```
const Investment_manager = sequelize.define('investment_manager', {
    im_id : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    im_name : {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
    // Other fields ....
});
```

a **project** table

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    project_id : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    project_name : {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    // Other fields ....
});
```

a **asso_project_im** table

```
const Asso_project_im = sequelize.define('asso_project_im', {
    asso_id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    // Other fields ....
});
```

I connection the tables using **belongsToMany**

```
investment_manager.belongsToMany(project, {as: 'im', through: 'asso_project_im', foreign_key: 'im_id'});
project.belongsToMany(investment_manager, {as: 'project', through: 'asso_project_im', foreign_key: 'project_id'});
```

I want to create foreign key in Asso_project_im table named **'im_id'** and **'project_id'**, is there any way to do that? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you using migrations?

Comment: No, I didn't. What is it for?

Comment: remove 'as' in belongsToMany relationship

Comment: I tried, and the column name becomes 'investmentManagerImId' and 'projectProjectId'.

Comment: how can I set the column name?  I can do it on 1-M relationship by passing the foreign_key as parameter, but it is not work on belongsToMany relationship

Comment: In NOT `foreign_key`, the option is `foreignKey`

Comment: It works, thanks. Sorry for my silly typo....